how to construct an array on server that is passed to client as part of a script.JS file
I'm trying to build a small single page web application.  the application has the basic index.html script.JS and style.CSS files. The  body element  (in index.html)  sets up a button and an empty section element.   the script populates the section element with the first of two lists. currently  the script includes   the lists in array objects like the following:
let list_1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
let list_2 = [ 'd', 'e', 'f']

canBtn.innerText = "CAN'T"
tagLine.innerText = 'I can still ...'
list_1.forEach(el => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerText = el
    document.querySelector('.text-container').appendChild(div)

initially, the client renders the first list. After that, when the user clicks the button, the script  switches to  show the second  list. the button can be used to toggle between the lists.
what I  want to do  is build  each list by reading a corresponding file. Something like:
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8');
const lines = fileContent.split('\n');

this should create the array I'm looking for, but how do I include this in  the script.JS file sent to the client?
Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I only started learning JavaScript last month and node.JS a week ago so I am pretty new to this.
I've tried using node and EJS  templates. I was expecting, well at least hoping, to have the server read the files each time the pages  is  requested

Some research seems to be in order here: you are asking about how to implement server side rendering (SSR — the generation of HTML, JS, and other resources on the server).

As a general note @JonStewart, in your question you say your file extension for the page is .html, but if you want to use EJS to render your page it must be .ejs. And don't forget to app.set('view engine', 'ejs') and also app.set('views', 'path/to/your/views/folder') to have it easier.

@jsejcksn Not really, he's asking for dynamically reading files on the server and displaying the content on the client side. Still, a question already answered numerous times and doable with some research.

You cannot access the disk files from the frontend directly.
To achieve this you need two apps: frontend and backend. On the server side (backend) you should have a NodeJS app that has a route which returns the file data. You can achieve this using ExpressJs.
On the frontend you access that route to return info.
This is a basic approach:
Server side:
/**
 * Reads data from a file located at the given path.
 * @param {string} filePath - The path to the file.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} - Resolves with file contents as a string.
 */
async function readFileData(filePath) {
    try {
        const fileContent= await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8'); 
        const lines = fileContent.split('\n');
        return lines;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error reading file at ${filePath}:`, error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Define the route
app.get('/get-file-data', async (req, res) => {
    const filePath = req.query.path; 

    if (!filePath) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'File path is required as a query parameter.' });
    }

    try {
        const data = await readFileData(filePath);
        res.status(200).json({ content: data });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to read file', details: error.message });
    }
});

On the frontend side:
const fileContent = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/get-file-data?path=${encodeURIComponent(filePath)}`).then( res => res.json() );
console.log('File content:', fileContent);

The code on the frontend side must be inside a async function, or else it will throw a Syntaxerror.

but doesn't the onload  event occur on the client? The problem is that the file is on the server. I'm probably missing something.

I think I understood your question. See the edited response

Generally this answer is correct, but there are some mistakes. I fixed most of them in an edit, but the code will not run if simply copy-pasted. Test your code before posting it!

The code was meant as a guide, not to be copy-pasted into a real project :) There are a lot of details that need to be clarified

in a earlier version I had used fetch  to retrieve the lists as already formatted HTML (just  a  tag around each list element) and was planning to try the  approach from your response  in  my next attempt.  I posted the question first because I figured I was probably  unaware of a simple way to replace  the hard-coded array elements  in the  script.js  file with  something generated  dynamically
